# Understanding "Restrictions on Transversal Encoded Quantum Gate Sets"

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction

I am trying to understand a part from the article "Restrictions on Transversal Encoded Quantum Gate Sets" ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.4262)) by Eastin and Knill.

In the article they talk about the importance of transversal encoded gates for fault tolerant quantum computing. They prove that there can't be a gate set that works on a non trivial quantum code space $\mathcal C$ that is also universal and the gates are transversal.

I understand the claim, but I have tried to understand the proof for a couple of weeks and just cant wrap my mind around it.

Can someone help me understand the following paragraph from the article?

> An outline of the argument is as follows: The set of logical unitary product operators, $\mathcal G$, is a Lie subgroup of the Lie group of unitary product operators, $\mathcal T$. As a Lie group, $\mathcal G$ can be partitioned into cosets of the connected component of the identity, $\mathcal C$; these cosets form a discrete set, $\mathcal Q$. Using the fact that the Lie algebra of $\mathcal C$ is a subalgebra of $\mathcal T$, it can be shown that the connected component of the identity acts trivially for any local-error-detecting code. This implies that the number of logically distinct operators implemented by elements of $\mathcal G$ is limited to the cardinality of $\mathcal Q$. Due to to the compactness of $\mathcal T$, this number must be finite.   A finite number of operators can approximate infinitely many only up to some fixed accuracy; thus, $\mathcal G$, the set of logical unitary product operators, cannot be universal. Transversal operators may be viewed as product operators with respect to a transversal partitioning of the code, so the ability to detect an arbitrary error on a transversal part implies the nonexistence of a universal, transversal encoded gate set.

Thank you for any help :)